# PL SQL Oracle Function :: Dynamic Range Checking

Tags: plsql

I have written a function that accepts two parameters, one being a price point id, and here is that table

```
Create table PriceList
(
PListID number(8),
PriceListID number(8),
Pl_Qty number(5),
pl_Price number(4),
CONSTRAINT PriceList_PK PRIMARY KEY (PListID)
);
```

Sorry for the terrible spacing.
and here is the Function

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION PriceOfItem     (pricepointid
 pricelist.plistid%TYPE, qty deliveryline.qtyshipped%TYPE)  return
 varchar2 AS

 cursor pricepoint is 
 select pricelistid, pl_price, pl_qty   from
 pricelist  where pricelist.pricelistid = pricepointid;     
 pricescursor pricepoint%ROWTYPE;    
 BEGIN  
 open pricepoint;   
 LOOP   
 FETCH pricepoint into pricescursor;    
 EXIT WHEN pricepoint%NOTFOUND;

    IF  qty = pricescursor.pl_qty  THEN         
 return pricescursor.pl_price;  
 END IF;

    END LOOP;   
 close pricepoint;

  END PriceOfItem; /
```

Now what I am trying to do with the quantity sent in it is the price based on the ranges provided for example: PriceList table has a pricelistid and it is repeated for that specific record which is linked to another table(out of scope), and this is how it works

```
Pricelistid  Qty    Price
18888888,      0,       60
18888888,      500,     55
18888888,      1000,    50
```

The parameter qty that I send into the function is used to compare to the qty in the pricelist table, now in reality what I want if the qty sent in is 0-499 then return price 60, or if 500 to 999 then 55, 1000 and greater 50. I have done this before but for some reason I am just absolutely puzzled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your return statement in IF condition and on some cases it will not execute that is the reason and also you are returning in the loop, you must exit first if multiple records are processing. I modified the code, check the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION PriceOfItem     (pricepointid
 pricelist.plistid%TYPE, qty deliveryline.qtyshipped%TYPE)  return
 varchar2 AS

 cursor pricepoint is 
 select pricelistid, pl_price, pl_qty   from
 pricelist  where pricelist.pricelistid = pricepointid;     
 pricescursor pricepoint%ROWTYPE;
 vfound boolean := false;    
 BEGIN  
 open pricepoint;   
 LOOP   
 FETCH pricepoint into pricescursor;    
 EXIT WHEN pricepoint%NOTFOUND;

    IF  qty = pricescursor.pl_qty  THEN         
     vfound := true;
     exit; 
    end if;
 END IF;

    END LOOP;   
 close pricepoint;
if vfound then
  return pricescursor.pl_price;  
else
  -- if not found then also return something, its mandatory
  return '';
end if;
  END PriceOfItem; 
/
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't need a cursor or stored procedure, just your two bind variables.  Here is an example using `PriceListID = 18888888` and `Pl_Qty of 499`:

```
SELECT a.*
  FROM PriceList a
  WHERE a.PriceListID = 18888888
    AND a.Pl_Qty = (SELECT MIN(Pl_Qty)
                      FROM PriceList
                      WHERE PriceListID = a.PriceListID
                        AND Pl_Qty >= 499)
```

Update: wrapping it a function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION PriceOfItem(
    p_pricepointid pricelist.plistid%TYPE,
    p_qty          deliveryline.qtyshipped%TYPE)
RETURN varchar2
AS

    v_result_price pricelist.pl_price%TYPE;

BEGIN

    SELECT a.Price
      INTO v_result_price
      FROM PriceList a
      WHERE a.PriceListID = p_pricepointid
        AND a.Pl_Qty = (SELECT MIN(Pl_Qty)
                          FROM PriceList
                          WHERE PriceListID = a.PriceListID
                            AND Pl_Qty >= p_qty);

    RETURN v_result_price;

END PriceOfItem;
/
```